# Symfony page not found (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.2

I am new in Symfony and i am working on existing project. I have created crud with `doctrine:generate:crud`, but application returns me 404 page not found. I was debugging it with `debug:router` and `router:match` and everything was okay.

Here is my **controller**

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Backend;

use AppBundle\Controller\BackendController;
use AppBundle\Entity\CsobApiUsers;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


/**
 * CsobApiUsers controller.
 *
 * @Route("csobApiUsers")
 */

class CsobApiUsersController extends BackendController
{
    /**
     * Lists all csobApiUser entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="csobapiusers_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die(var_dump("x"));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $csobApiUsers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:CsobApiUsers')->findAll();

        return $this->render('csobapiusers/index.html.twig', array(
            'csobApiUsers' => $csobApiUsers,
        ));
    }
```

Controller is as same as another controller that works correctly.

Here is my **router:match**

```
php bin/console router:match /backend/csobApiUsers/



 [OK] Route "csobapiusers_index" matches


+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | csobapiusers_index                                      |
| Path         | /backend/csobApiUsers/                                  |
| Path Regex   | #^/backend/csobApiUsers/$#s                             |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | GET                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: AppBundle:Backend\CsobApiUsers:index       |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is **debug:router** for my controller

```
 csobapiusers_index                           GET          ANY      ANY    /backend/csobApiUsers/
  csobapiusers_new                             GET|POST     ANY      ANY    /backend/csobApiUsers/new
  csobapiusers_show                            GET          ANY      ANY    /backend/csobApiUsers/{id}
  csobapiusers_edit                            GET|POST     ANY      ANY    /backend/csobApiUsers/{id}/edit
  csobapiusers_delete                          DELETE       ANY      ANY    /backend/csobApiUsers/{id}
```

I calling ***https://my-address.com/backend/csobApiUsers/***

**Does anybody know where can be problem? Thanks**

Comment: Do you have any route declaration with /backend/{some_dynamic_pattern} loaded before this one ? It can cause your path to be handled by the wrong controller because the router try to match routes from top to bottom declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing slash in controller route annotation, check here https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-prefix-all-controller-route-names

```
@Route("/csobApiUsers")
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try changing your indexAction() to index() instead ?

Comment: Yes, but without change. Still 404 page not found

Comment: Replace @Route("/") with @Route("/backend/csobApiUsers")

Comment: Still without change. Still 404 page not found

Comment: Better check your BackendController, is there a function named index in this file and if you has changed some line of code, try clearing the cache.
After all, there might be a log file in your var/log/dev.log. Check its content you may find the errors